# Invoke Java program

Tags: wso2

Can we invoke a java program from a BPEL process using invoke activity? I am looking for something similar to invoking an external web service. But instead of the web service I need to invoke a java program.

Regards
-Albin

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done with WSO2 Business Process Server.
A sample location:

[1]https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/denis/org.wso2.carbon.bpel.extension.activity.sample/

Also you can refer to following articles, it provides more information on how to write an extension activity to achieve this.

[2] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BPS300/BPEL+Extensibility

[3] http://warunapw.blogspot.com/2009/11/how-to-write-bpel-extension-for-wso2.html

[4] http://ddweerasiri.blogspot.com/2012/04/ws-bpel-20-extension-activity.html

Thanks

Thilini